abbreviation stops expanding with "/"
The following problem with ab is seriously annoying me (seems to have started with vim 9.1):
In my .vimrc, I have ab FF ftp://test.com/www.
This will usually be expanded with e.g. / when I type the command :e FF/page.html to :e ftp://test.com/www/page.html.
However, sometime after using vim for a few minutes (?!), typing / after FF stops invoking the abbreviation?!
I then need to use a work-around of e.g. FF (space) and then BACKSPACE and / to expand it.
What's happened? How can I fix it? Any ideas?
Thanks.

"Any ideas?" Yes, see if the problem persists with $ vim -Nu NONE. If it doesn't, then the problem comes from somewhere in your config. If it does, then you may have found a bug in Vim, which you should report using its issue tracker.

When this happens, please show us :verbose set iskeyword?

See How to debug my vimrc
